# Function not returning random integer for variable

Tags: python, random

I have a very simple problem, when I run the following code:

```
from random import randint

def create_random():
  x = random.randint(1,4)
  return x 

print(create_random)
```

The output comes to this:

```
< function create_random at 0x7f5994bd4f28 >
```

Note: every character between "0x7f" and "f28" are random each time the code is run.

My goal was to be able to call the function multiple times with x being assigned a new integer value between 1 and 3 with each invocation.

Comment: You forgot to call the function. Try `print(create_random())` instead?

Comment: FYI: The code as it is won't work. If you do `from random import randint` you have to use `x = randint(1,4)` (without the module name). Your call with the module name would run if you did `import random`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't actually calling the function. To do this you need to do:

```
print(create_random())
```

Just now you're printing the reference to the function which isn't very helpful for you in this case.

Comment: Yikes. I'm embarrassed to admit I spent over an hour pondering why I had this wrong, I think in my head I assumed I didn't have to call it because there were no parameters. I'm pretty new if you hadn't already guessed that. Thanks though to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function, like:

```
print(create_random())
```

Also in the function, this line:

```
x = random.randint(1,4)
```

Should be just:

```
x = randint(1,4)
```

Since you did a `from ... import ...` statement.

Answer (score 0):

your last line does not do anything, since you want it to print 'create_random' that is not a variable. if you want to call a function, it has to have (). So, you should call it and put it in the print function:

print(create_random())